# How to get the next page JSON string?

Tags: json, api, url, gitlab-api

I used the API URL to get the JSON string in my browser. But I did some modification in my URL. So now I don`t know how to go for next page of JSON string!.

I early use the URL `http://gitlab.company.com/api/v3/users?per_page=100&page=1`. In this URL I simply the `page=2` or `page=3`... and get the value. But now I modified the URL like `http://gitlab.company.com/api/v3/users?private_token=GMxxyyzz9e8umondgBL`.

Now I do not know how to get the 100 results (`per_page=100`) per page and also I don`t know how to get the JSON string up to the last page (`page=1`).

I tried some changes in the new URL and run it. But I receive the `401 unauthorized error`

**Note**: I get the JSON string by manually(By using the browser). Not a code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly use below format

http://gitlab.company.com/api/v3/users?private_token=GMxxyyzz9e8umondgBL&per_page=100&page=1

for next page

http://gitlab.company.com/api/v3/users?private_token=GMxxyyzz9e8umondgBL&per_page=100&page=2